# Distinguishing bitcoin deposits

Tags: transactions, signature, javascript, message-signing, deposit

If i had a central Bitcoin wallet, and then allowed 3 different people to deposit bitcoin into that address, would there be anyway to distinguish who they are, without knowing who's address is who, i know sending messages with transactions isn't supported by all wallets so i was just wondering if there was a different way.

Like i said i've tried passing a message through the transaction but that isn't always possible from the wallets.

Maybe theres another way to check someone is the owner of a wallet. Other than signing a message of course.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the only way to distinguish incoming payments is by some combination of

- **sending address** (usually arbitrary and not always known in advance)
- **amount** (could be same for many people if you are selling fixed-price widgets)
- **receiving address** (no good if you give everyone the same address to send money to)

That is one reason why best practice is to generate a new receiving address per transaction.